# I am trying to send data from android app to localhost but data are not submit on localhost

Tags: java, php, android

i am trying to send data from my android app to localhost but data are not submit on localhost.I already create php file(register.php) and save in www directory.That php file work fine when i manually submit data. 
below is my MainActivity.java file.

```
public void onButtonClickListener()
    {
        on_submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.onsubmit);
        on_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               String str_personname = personname.getText().toString();
                String str_contactno = contactno.getText().toString();
                String str_alternateno = alternateno.getText().toString();
                String str_emailid = emailid.getText().toString();
                String str_currentline1 = currentline1.getText().toString();
                String str_currentline2 = currentline2.getText().toString();
                String str_currentlocality = currentlocality.getText().toString();
                String str_currentcity = currentcity.getText().toString();
                String str_currentstate = currentstate.getText().toString();
                String str_currentpin = currentpin.getText().toString();
                String str_permanentline1 = permanentline1.getText().toString();
                String str_permanentline2 = permanentline2.getText().toString();
                String str_permanentlocality = permanentlocality.getText().toString();
                String str_permanentcity = permanentcity.getText().toString();
                String str_permanentstate = permanentstate.getText().toString();
                String str_permanentpin = permanentpin.getText().toString();
                String str_dateofinterview = dateofinterview.getText().toString();
                String str_applyfor = applyfor.getText().toString();
                String str_refrencename = refrencename.getText().toString();
                String str_refrenceid = refrenceid.getText().toString();
                 String type = "register";
                Backendworker backendworker = new Backendworker(MainActivity.this);
                backendworker.execute(type, str_personname, str_contactno, str_alternateno, str_emailid, str_currentline1, str_currentline2, str_currentlocality, str_currentcity,
                        str_currentstate, str_currentpin, str_permanentline1, str_permanentline2, str_permanentlocality, str_permanentcity, str_permanentstate,
                        str_permanentpin, str_dateofinterview, str_applyfor, str_refrencename, str_refrenceid);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Action performed on button click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

i already definde their id in oncreate() method.
below is my Backendworker.java class

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;


public class Backendworker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Backendworker(Context ctx) {

        context = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String register_url = "http://my ip address or local host/register.php";

       if(type.equals("register")) {
            try {
                String personname1 = params[1];
                String contactno1 = params[2];
                String alternateno1 = params[3];
                String emailid1  = params[4];
                String currentline11 = params[5];
                String currentline21 = params[6];
                String currentlocality1 = params[7];
                String currentcity1 = params[8];
                String currentstate1 = params[9];
                String currentpin1 = params[10];
                String permanentline11 = params[11];
                String permanentline21 = params[12];
                String permanentlocality1 = params[13];
                String permanentcity1 = params[14];
                String permanentstate1= params[15];
                String permanentpin1 = params[16];
                String dateofinterview1 = params[17];
                String applyfor1 = params[18];
                String refencename1 = params[19];
                String refrenceid1 = params[20];




                URL url = new URL(register_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("personname", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(personname1, "UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("contactno", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(contactno1, "UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("alternateno", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(alternateno1, "UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("emailid", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(emailid1, "UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("currentline1", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(currentline11, "UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("currentline2", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(currentline21, "UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("currentlocality", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(currentlocality1, "UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("currentcity", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(currentcity1, "UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("currentstate", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(currentstate1, "UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("currentpin","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(currentpin1,"UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("permanentline1","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(permanentline11,"UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("permanentline2","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(permanentline21,"UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("permanentlocality","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(permanentlocality1,"UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("permanentcity","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(permanentcity1,"UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("permanentstate","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(permanentstate1,"UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("permanentpin","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(permanentpin1,"UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("dateofinterview","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(dateofinterview1,"UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("applyfor","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(applyfor1,"UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("refrencename","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(refencename1,"UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("refrenceid","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(refrenceid1,"UTF-8");
                        //+ "&" +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

code does not show any error anywhere.
below is php file

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$personname=$_POST["personname"];
$contactno=$_POST["contactno"];
$alternateno=$_POST["alternateno"];
$emailid=$_POST["emailid"];
$currentline1=$_POST["currentline1"];
$currentline2=$_POST["currentline2"];
$currentlocality=$_POST["currentlocality"];
$currentcity=$_POST["currentcity"];
$currentstate=$_POST["currentstate"];
$currentpin=$_POST["currentpin"];
$permanentline1=$_POST["permanentline1"];
$permanentline2=$_POST["permanentline2"];
$permanentlocality=$_POST["permanentlocality"];
$permanentcity=$_POST["permanentcity"];
$permanentstate=$_POST["permanentstate"];
$permanentpin=$_POST["permanentpine"];
$dateofinterview=$_POST["dateofinterview"];
$applyfor=$_POST["applyfor"];
$refrencename=$_POST["refrencename"];
$refrenceid=$_POST["refrenceid"];
$mysql_qry="insert into applicant(personname,contactno,alternateno,emailid,currentline1,currentline2,currentlocality,currentcity,currentstate,currentpin,permanentline1,permanentline2,permanentlocality,permanentcity,permanentstate,permanentpin,dateofinterview,applyfor,refrencename,refrenceid) values('$personname','$contactno','$alternateno','$emailid','$currentline1','$currentline2','$currentlocality','$currentcity','$currentstate','$currentpin','$permanentline1','$permanentline2','$permanentlocality','$permanentcity','$permanentstate','$permanentpin','$dateofinterview','$applyfor','$refrencename','$refrenceid')";

if($conn->query($mysql_qry)===TRUE)
{
echo "insert successful";
}
else
{
echo "insert unsuccessful";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

if anyone know the ans then please help.
thanks...

Comment: Are the data not submitted TO !ocalhost or are they not received on localhost?

Comment: data are not submitted on localhost and also localhost not send any confirmation

Comment: `from my android app to localhost`. For your Android app localhost is the device where it runs on. Is there a server on your phone/tablet that will receive sent data?

Comment: i connect it with my ip address

Comment: Your phone/tablet has an ip addres. Thats your ip address? Every device has a different ip address.

Comment: i already try all the option....but not work

Comment: All the option? Which options? Pretty unclear what you are doing. Please be clear in explaining your setup if you want help. Be to the point. We still dont know where you try to connect with and to send to. Also change your concept of localhost and show us that you did.

Comment: localhost means my wamp server which is installed in my pc.

Comment: and ip address which connect my laptop...

Comment: If the server is installed on your pc then why do you use ip of laptop?

Comment: server ip not working so, i used ip of laptop

Comment: @BHAGAT it may be that your Server should rather listen on 0.0.0.0 rather than 127.0.0.1?  See here: http://www.howtogeek.com/225487/what-is-the-difference-between-127.0.0.1-and-0.0.0.0/

Comment: If your wamp server is on your pc it makes no sense using the ip of your laptop. You are not seriously answering on comments. Why not? You want help isnt it?

Comment: the default ip address to connect my app with localhost is 10.0.2.2 or 127.0.0.1 both of them are not working in my case then i saw video which told that if your default ip is not working then connect it with your system ip.so i connect it with my system ip but still that was not working

Comment: now 10.0.2.2 is working on my custom amulator(AVD)  but not on my device.....I don't know why.

Comment: `the default ip address to connect my app with localhost is 10.0.2.2 or 127.0.0.1`. No. That is not true as a rule. And now you suddenly speak about a 'system ip' where you did not answer my comment concerning a change from pc ip to laptop ip. Please start to answer remarks to the point.